# Script to turn off Wacom Bamboo touch randomly stops working

Tags: scripts, wacom

I've created a script to turn off the Wacom Bamboo touch.

```
#!/bin/bash
xsetwacom set "Bamboo 16 FG 4x5 Finger touch" touch off
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser" touch off
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad" touch off
```

I put the script in my start up applications, and it always works initially, but then after a few hours it stops randomly and the touch goes back on. There seems to be no rhyme or reason - when I execute the script again, touch turns off again.

I'm wondering if it's a problem with the script itself...?

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a bit of a dud way out but... if it turns off after a little while, have you considered using     cron to re-run it every hour or so?

Comment: Hey, I'll try anything. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Sure thing. Check you have the cron daemon first off with `which cron`. If it comes up with a directory then you have it. If not, use apt-get to install it. After that, type `crontab -e`. That opens the cron daemon. Now type in `00 00-23 * * * /directory/to/<script-name>`. If you need to turn this off at any time, just run `crontab -e` again and comment out the line you just added. Let me know if you need any further information

Comment: The above code will run your script every hour, on the hour. You can change the when according to the notes in the crontab itself. Hope this helps =)

Comment: Darn. It's turning itself back on again every few minutes, now, so I don't think the every hour solution will work. Do you think it could be a problem with the script?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the script, it seems a

Comment: Sorry, hit enter prematurely. See text of reply here: That's pretty strange. All your script is doing is running three commands that you would otherwise run in the terminal. Try running `xsetwacom --list-devices` and noting the device **number** and **type** e.g. `Pen eraser id:12 type:ERASER` and then invoking individual commands for each of them. Your new script would then be more along the lines of `#!/bin/bash //newline xsetwacom set 12 eraser off //newline xsetwacom 13 touch off //newline xsetwacom 14 pad off`, using your own output devices for each one obviously

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the device number changes from session to session. I did the above cron change, but it randomly turned touch back on during the hour wait for the script to run again.

Comment: I don't know much about cron - is there a good reason to keep it at 1 hour, or could I change it to every 5 minutes without hurting anything else?

Comment: It wouldnt hurt anything at all - all cron does is run scripts for you - it would be the equivalent of running the script manually every 5 minutes, but cron makes life so much simpler =)

Comment: Hooray! I'll do that, then. Thanks so much for your help.